# Path metrics without geodesics

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

This is a follow-up of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/994260/shortest-path-in-complete-metric-space/995956?noredirect=1#comment2036942_995956). Recall that a metric space $(X,d)$ is called a *path-metric space* if the distance between any two points in $X$ equals the infimum of lengths of paths between these points. Such $(X,d)$ contains a plenty of rectifiable paths (unless $X$ is either empty or is a one-point set). A *geodesic* between the two points $x, y\in X$ is a 
path $c$ from $x$ to $y$, whose length equals the distance $d(x,y)$.

**Question.** Is there a complete path-metric space $(X,d)$ (consisting of more than one point) such the only geodesics in $(X,d)$ are constant maps to $X$? (I think so, but do not see a clear proof.)

Obviously, such space $X$ cannot be locally compact (at any point).

Note that in the example given in the linked question, there are pairs of points without geodesics connecting them. Another example (an infinite-dimensional complete Hilbert manifold) is mentioned in [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf%E2%80%93Rinow_theorem). However, in both examples, the space contains plenty of geodesics.

Note. For the record: I asked this question first [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/997198/path-metrics-without-geodesics).

**Edit.** I just discovered that the same question was posted by Anton Petrunin (in 2010) and answered (by fedja) on Mathoverflow [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/15592/intrinsic-metric-with-no-geodesics?rq=1). Sadly, the only way to find out was to post this question and then to check the list of similar questions. Feel free to close as a duplicate.